# Delayed_job in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now my Usermailer is written so I have UserMailer.delay.deliver_blah.  Everything works perfect, but like before I'd like the contents of the email printed out in the console for debugging.  HOw do I do this?

Comment: Do you want the contents displayed at the time you call the `.delay` or at the time the delayed job processes/sends the mail?  I believe delayed job will still output based on the env, but it will go to the delayed_job.log file instead.  That does depend on which branch you are using though.  I can say that is what happens in the collectiveidea branch.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ActionMailer logger and set the correct log level, during mailer initialization.

```
ActionMailer::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActionMailer::Base.logger.level = :info
```

OR

```
ActionMailer::Base.logger = Rails.logger
ActionMailer::Base.logger.level = :info
```